# Trying to figure out how to get count in date ranges in Redis

Tags: php, database-design, redis

I am trying to store something like the following...

I have a system which has keywords, these keywords can be right or wrong. I want to store the every time someone enters a wrong keyword (as well as the specific application they where on and a timestamp).

`timestamp - application#1` and I'd like it to be inside it's own key.

I need to then be able to go "Okay how many people got a keyword wrong between TIMESTAMP1 and TIMESTAMP2 that tried using application #1"

Is there any other way I could do this? If the last part (that tried using application #1) won't work which I suspect as this isn't SQL. Then could it return the value of application #1 so I can do the last part in PHP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis does not support key wildcards so you have to select the keys client side.

This means you have to get batches of keys and combine the results together; if thats not always possible (eg. big ranges, ms key naming resolution...) you should consider keeping aggregates (keyword per hour / keyword per day ...)

If you use sets / sorted sets to store the keywords have a look at the set specific commands (UNION / UNIONSTORE in specific) as they might come handy for this :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but i have a solution for the problem with `sorted sets`.

- You will have different `sorted sets` with the combination of `appName` and `wrong keyword` such as `myapp1:wrongword`, `myapp2:anotherwrongword`, `myanotherapp:yetanotherwrongword`... will be the keys.
- Whenever a user enters a wrong keyword in an application you will use `ZADD` with `unique identifier`(created in your application layer such as UUID) as value and a `timestamp`(entered time) as `score` to the sorted set. The identifier has to be unique because if you put user id, then whenever the same user enters a wrong keyword in the same application at a different time it will overwrite the `score` of the sorted set.
- Then you can use `ZCOUNT` to calculate

> how many people got a keyword wrong between `TIMESTAMP1` and `TIMESTAMP2` that tried using application #1"

For simplicity; i used small numbers as timestamp(`score`), your app name is `myapp` and the wrong keyword is `wrong1`. The arbitrary letters are the unique ids generated at your application layer.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD myapp:wrong1 123 abcdef 123 defg 126 xyz 132 qpr 145 ypz
(integer) 5
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE myapp:wrong1 0 -1 WITHSCORES
 1) "abcdef"
 2) "123"
 3) "defg"
 4) "123"
 5) "xyz"
 6) "126"
 7) "qpr"
 8) "132"
 9) "ypz"
10) "145"
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGEBYSCORE myapp:wrong1 123 127
1) "abcdef"
2) "defg"
3) "xyz"
127.0.0.1:6379> ZCOUNT myapp:wrong1 123 127
(integer) 3
127.0.0.1:6379> ZCOUNT myapp:wrong1 123 126
(integer) 3
127.0.0.1:6379> ZCOUNT myapp:wrong1 123 125
(integer) 2
```

While using `ZCOUNT` you may use your timestamp intervals to get total number of users as described [here](https://redis.io/commands/zcount).